# How to find and print pdf files in a directory then delete after printing?

Tags: javascript, filesystems, html5-filesystem

I have a button that generates a pdf file then downloads it automatically.

I want to print the files automatically after they have been saved into a location. I have added

> --kiosk-printing

in a chrome shortcut for it to print directly to a default printer without showing the print preview dialogue. What i need is JavaScript to

1. check directory (C:/Downloads
2. find file (in a loop maybe)
3. print file (window.print)
4. delete that file

if it's possible with JavaScript. I could do it with bash but i can't execute a bash script in a html button.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up creating a batch file

```
#!/bin/bash
START C:\Users\johnsmith\PDFtoPrinter.exe %userprofile%\Downloads\boxlabel.pdf
timeout 5
del /f %userprofile%\Downloads\boxlabel.pdf
```

and added that to the Windows Task Scheduler that runs every 1 minute to print the pdf. It's a pity i can't make it run every 5 seconds et, the task scheduler is only limited to atmost 1 minutes in repeats.